# [Solved[ Streming prime video won't work in Chromium

Tags: video-streaming, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I just installed a Raspberry Media Center for streaming from Netflix/Crunchyroll/Youtube/Prime Video/Files from Network with Kodi. Everything works besides streaming from Prime Video. That leaves me wondering why that might be since I can stream from Netflix / Crunchyroll.

- libwidevinecdm0 is installed
- Chromium is on the latest version available from repositories (Version: 106.0.5249.119-1~deb11u1)
- Raspberry Pi is 4b and the os is the latest one

Could anyone give me a hint what I could check or do next? Can I provide more useful info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All right... I solved it, I guess. I had the Media Extension installed for chrome. To be sure I got rid of everything I just purged both chromium and libwidevine and reinstalled them. Now everything is working just fine.